# what is the main function of uniqid(”, true)?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm studying a login system at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/.

And I want to ask, what is the main function of `uniqid(”, true)`?
The tutorial from the website says

*"user unique id – I am generating unique user id in php using uniqid(”, true) function. Sample user id will be like 4f074eca601fb8.88015924"*

Why it must generate the user id? For security or for what?

Thank you so much guys.

This is the *mysql* query for my database.

```
create table users(
uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(100) not null unique,
encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
salt varchar(10) not null,
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

Comment: Sidenote: Curly quotes will kill your code.

Comment: [`Read the manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think the OP is asking what the purpose of the unique ID is in this situation, not how `uniqid` works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this unique_id is used for data submission. For example, submitting a form with ajax may require the user id of the person submitting it, so to prevent hackers from changing the data sent to the server, unique id are used to make the change almost useless cuz they don't know the pattern of how people are assigned IDs. Another reason, unique id might be useful in, it might be used in the url to show the profile of someone. example: profile.php?id=unique_long_id 
This prevents people from knowing how many users exist in the website ...
There is unlimited ways you can be creative with unique ids :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, something like a "complex" (understand not an auto_increment thing) id is used so that no user can guess an other user's id.

If you used something like the uid (the primary key auto_increment column), it would be easy to guess that users 145th, 146th, ... exist. A user may try to brute force some requests manipulating the id.

In a badly coded website where you don't have any security check before updating a value, let's assume you have this URL to update a password : `http://example.com/update_password?uid=150&password=trolling`. Easy to change any users password right ? But with the unique_id, it's more complex.

Now why the 2 arguments in uniqid('',true) ? Because from the manual :

```
/* We can also activate the more_entropy parameter, which is 
* required on some systems, like Cygwin. This makes uniqid()
* produce a value like: 4b340550242239.64159797
*/
```